# Como desserializar atributos dos elementos de um XML com C#?

Tags: c#, xml

Bom ja fiz essa pergunta uma vez mas não tive resposta, então vou perguntar novamente. Já tentei alguns métodos que vi aí que falavam que funcionava em outras perguntas, mas nenhum deu conta.

Eu preciso ler essa XML:

http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=BISA3|PETR4|PETR3

E extrair os atributos dos elementos para jogar em um banco de dados. A parte do banco eu já sei fazer, só estou com dificuldades em jogar os valores dos atributos em variáveis para parametrizar. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Não acho que é duplicata. Ele quer uma desserialização, não necessariamente ler atributo a atributo, senão a resposta indicada atenderia perfeitamente.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez na verdade é a mesma pergunta, só escrita de forma diferente.

Comment: Eu ia intervir na pergunta anterior também, mas achei que a duplicata pudesse ajudar. Como não resolveu, coloco outra resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você quer, na verdade é uma **desserialização**: transformar um XML em um objeto que possa ser lido e preencher variáveis para persistir no seu banco.

Abaixo detalho um roteiro que pode servir para o seu problema.

## Lendo o XML

Esta primeira etapa exige que se abra uma requisição para o site e leia a resposta (que é o XML). O código abaixo faz isso:

```
using System.Net.Http;

var client = new HttpClient();

var uri = new Uri("http://www.bmfbovespa.com.br/Pregao-Online/ExecutaAcaoAjax.asp?CodigoPapel=BISA3|PETR4|PETR3");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

## Convertendo a resposta em XML

Se `response` estiver ok, temos que ler o XML. Como seu XML não tem `namespace`, o procedimento de leitura é mais simples e pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseString);
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/ComportamentoPapeis/*");

    foreach (XmlNode childNode in nodes)
    {
        switch (childNode.Name)
        {
            case "Papel":
                // Coloque sua lógica de negócios aqui.
                // A dica que dou pro seu caso é ler childNode.Attributes.
                break;
        }
    }
```

Se precisar, coloco uma prova de conceito no GitHub.

Comment: Obrigado isso funcionou eu dei umas ajustadas aqui para adequar a minha lógica e funcionou obrigado mesmo , desculpe por incomodar e fazer duas perguntas idênticas e que nessa eu queria ser mais especifico do que n outra ajudou bastante mesmo vlw :)

Comment: @Filipe Eu que peço desculpas por não ter tentado essa resposta antes. Eu tinha um código muito parecido aqui já pronto que adaptei pra sua realidade. Fique à vontade para perguntar mais em caso de mais dúvidas.